# Googlesheet merge 2 cells in next column based on their content

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a Googlesheet with Column A= ID like B-124992 or D-133739 and several different ID's as well, Column B= Title description. I want to Merge only the "B-" and "D-" -like ID's with their respective Title description. I'm using ArrayFormula in column C like:

```
= ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND({"B-","D-"};'BacklogData'!A2));A2&" - "&B2;""))
```

The result is merging as expected but the output is distributed in column C (shows all "B-" merge results) and column D ((shows all "D-" merge results).

**How can I get the results all in column C?**

Comment: Why do you need an array formula - wouldn't `=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,2)="B-",LEFT(A2,2)="D-"),A2&" - "&B2,"")` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C2 try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B); if(regexmatch(A2:A; "(B-|D-)"); A2:A&"-"&B2:B;);))
```

This will reference the colA and output the concatenation of col A and colB if col A starts with either B- or D.
NOTE: you will have to erase all formulas you currently have in col C.

Hope that helps ?

EDIT: not sure if you are referencing another sheet, but in that case you will have to add in the sheet name, like you did in the example you gave.

Comment: This ArrayFormula also works great! I decided for the previous solution as I understand it easier. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an array formula for this - all you need is an `OR` condition in a standard formula:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,2)="B-",LEFT(A2,2)="D-"),A2&" - "&B2,"")
```

and copy as far down column C as you need.  Since this is not an array, it will only return one result per cell which is what you want.

Comment: While this also works, the Arrayformula eliminates the need to drag down. That way you'll need only one formula, instead of n formulas.